# Contents of boost::shared_ptr as key for set?

Tags: c++, boost, set

I'd like to store a series of pointers in an `std::unordered_set`. I'd like the hash function to be based not on the memory address, but on some values contained within the actual object referenced by the pointer.

e.g. (`using std` and `boost` namespaces for readability)

```
class MyClass {
  ...
  //some values I want to use as the key for the hash
  double a;
  int b;
  int c;
}

typedef shared_ptr<MyClass> MyClassPtr;

set<MyClassPtr> mySet;
```

I'm not worried about combining the actual hash values (found answer here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html), but rather dereferencing the `shared_ptr` to get the keys.

The other concern I have is that the `== operator` is already definied for `boost::shared_ptr`, and I was wondering if this would cause problems with my approach? I'd need to test equality against the object, not the pointer.

Storing pointers in the set because several other parts of the code are referencing the objects via their own pointers. Any alternative approaches are welcomed as well.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `unordered_set<MyClassPtr>`?  `std::set` uses a strict weak ordering, not hash values.

Answer (score 5):

What's the problem? Define a hash function and equality and on you go:

```
struct MyClassHash
{
  inline std::size_t operator()(const MyClassPtr & p)
  {
    return 4;  //  prone to hash collisions, improve on this
  }
};

struct MyClassEqual
{
  inline bool operator()(const MyClassPtr & p, const MyClassPtr & q)
  {
    return false; // implement
  }
};

typedef std::unordered_set<MyClassPtr, MyClassHash, MyClassEqual> MySet;
```

Note that the two functors (hash and equality) have to be written as classes; free functions don't work. (The container keeps a private *instance* of the functors around.) This is somewhat annoying, but since you'll only be doing this once, it shouldn't be so bad.

Normally I'd recommend specializing `std::hash` and `std::equals`, but I'd hesitate to do that with something so general as a shared pointer, since it might easily confuse others who don't expect those specializations.

Comment: +1 for `//  prone to hash collisions, improve on this`. (It is [guaranteed random](http://xkcd.com/221/), though!)

Comment: Why not functions? `typedef std::unordered_set<MyClassPtr, std::size_t (*)(const MyClassPtr & p), bool (*)(const MyClassPtr & p, const MyClassPtr & q)> MySet; MySet m(42, &my_hash_func, &my_pred_func);`

Comment: @dalle: Hm, I think I tried that but couldn't make it work ... in any case, that means that the functor isn't default-constructible and you have to keep that clunky constructor around all the time. With empty-base optimizations, the class-based approach shouldn't be any worse.

Comment: I agree, the functor based approch would probably be faster anyway due to inlining and such,

Comment: @dalle, not to mention the function approach is nigh unreadable.